# Issue library DT renderDataTable

Tags: shiny, dt

I met an issue with the DT library in R used in a shiny app.

When I run this following code (famous exemple of the library) in an empty environement :

```
   library(shiny)
   shinyApp(
   ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
   server = function(input, output) {
   output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
   iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
 }
)
```

all is ok.

However, when I use this code in my current application in which I loaded many .js codes and many R packages, the table is not displayed on my interface. Whereas, when I use the functions dataTableOutput and renderDataTable from the shiny package, all is ok again.

Did someone meet this issue or have an idea to solve it ?

Thanks !

Mez13.

Comment: R packages shouldn't effect it, but I suppose you could be including some conflicting js codes, but without seeing what you include it is impossible to know.

Comment: @Carl I include only "famous" .js codes to plot some highcharts, they all come from  <http://code.highcharts.com/> . Nevertheless, when I try to read the source code (f12) of the web page in which my application displays : I see that the table is here (in the code, not in real) and they talk about an error reguarding the jsQuery.min.js, but the fact is that I do not use this code. Do you have any idea ?